# View HTML source of file loaded in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)

I want the html source code of the html file that has been loaded into my WebView. 
By searching a lot, I came to know that it should done using the WebViewClient. Can anyone tell me how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice on this question [Is there a way to get the HTML in a webview in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543663/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-html-in-a-webview-in-an-android-app) may help.

Comment: no i cant get idea still

Answer (score -1):

The Android WebView source code can be found here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebView.java

Comment: Question was not about getting source code of WebView control