# How I get page source from WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

How I get the web page's source from WebView?

I want to only enter www.google.com in my webview and When I entered this site, I want to get the source for example

```
String a=........;(source)
```

Comment: Do you want the whole source code or just the HTML tags?

Comment: I want to whole source code . (for example when I paste it in .txt and open it with browser I want to see the site )

Comment: Yes I do and I have submitted an edit and I am now flagging this as a exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543663/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-html-in-a-webview-in-an-android-app

Comment: I m sorry.I do not Understand really.What you mean addJavascriptInterface(). it is static where can ı find this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure how far this is going to be helpful. But I have used the below snippet to fetch a small html page's data. I hope it helps you.

Create a class like the one below,

```
  class MyJavaScriptInterface
  {
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      public void processHTML(final String html)
      {
          Log.i("processed html",html);

            Thread OauthFetcher=new Thread(new Runnable() { 

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String oAuthDetails=null;
                      oAuthDetails=Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
                      Log.i("oAuthDetails",oAuthDetails);

                }
            });OauthFetcher.start();
        }
      }
```

Now in your onCreate(),

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {


                String oAuthUrl=getString("www.google.com");

                if(url.contains(oAuthUrl))
                {
                    Log.i("Contains","Auth URL");

                    twitter_webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressDialog.show();
            }
      });
```

And now what happens is that, when your page finishes loading, the JavaScript class will be called, which would retrieve the page source and store it in a String as your requirement.

Comment: Bitmap and progressDialogit does not seen and does not import,I change twitter_webview to webvie ? what can ı do

Comment: isn't that the question is all about? To fetch the page source? That's why I read the page source as a String and store it..

Comment: sorry. Got your question wrong. The thread is to avoid any interference to the Main UI thread. if the web page, then to download its content into a string will take a long time. If we dont do this in a secondary thread, then the main thread gets blocked and you might get ANR dialog.

Comment: @JavascriptInterface annotation should be there in processHTML() method.

Answer (score 7):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or greater you can use the following.

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    view?.evaluateJavascript("""(function() {
        return "<html>" + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + "</html>";
    })()""".trimMargin()) {
        console.log(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**And For API 17**

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context myApp = this;

@JavascriptInterface
public void processHTML(String html) {
    if (html == null)
        return;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(this, "HTMLOUT");
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.il");
}

}
```