# How to get html sourcecode of webpage loaded in webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to get the html source code of a webpage loaded in `webview` element. I want the source code in text format to parse it further.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966760/how-i-get-page-source-from-webview)
does that but it reloads the page from network for the purpose. I do not want to do that since that will waste time. How to achieve this ?

Comment: [The only way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)