# how can I acces webview content?

Tags: android, json, webview

How can I acces webview content on my Android? I have read this post : [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)
but it suggested to use embeded javascript which cause me `@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")` 
warning so I have decided not to use this method. Can I anyhow acces the content of the body via `WebViewClient()` ? I also get the content via Json in body but I can not acces any entity to read it.

```
.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.equalsIgnoreCase(the_url)){                  
                    //here get the content
                }
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
        });
```

I want achieve something similar to

```
final HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

or just simply read the whole String between `<body>...</body>`

the explanation: I want to log in the user on my website, for security reason I need to load url with the formular, when the user is loged in as response I get both Json with some security token and it is echoed so it looks like this:`<body>{"token":"abcd"}</body>` But I need that token, and I need that on every device, so I have to find a way how can I read it from JSON or from the webpage. please help me with that.

thanks

Comment: don't get to you extra problem, JavaScriptInterface normally working. See this links: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966760/how-i-get-page-source-from-webview , 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

Comment: I just do not believe that the web view cant tell me what content is in it. Thats fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I acces webview content on my Android?

Use the techniques outlined in the answer, using `addJavascriptInterface()` to register a callback, then using `loadUrl()` to execute a `javascript:` URL that retrieves the portion of the DOM that you want and passes it to some method on your callback.

> it suggested to use embeded javascript which cause me @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface") warning

Correct, because if you are loading arbitrary content, that content could try calling your callback when you do not expect it.

> so I have decided not to use this method

Then you cannot "acces webview content".

> Can I anyhow acces the content of the body via WebViewClient() ?

No.