# How to get HTML content from WebView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

**I am trying to get the HTML content of a webview as a string in Kotlin.** I need to get the HTML of what the webview is showing, **not the HTML of the URL it's showing.** That is because the user is supposed to log in on the website, and if I try to get the HTML from the URL I only get the HTML from the login page.

This is how I'm currently getting the HTML from a URL:

```
class ReadFileTask{

    fun getTextFromWeb(urlString: String) {
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                val url = URL(urlString)
                val con = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection

                val datas = con.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                Log.d("HTML content", datas)

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d("Exception", ex.toString())
            }
        }).start()
    }
}
```

Else I haven't done anything to my WebView besides adding a WebViewClient that makes it open URLs inside the webview. It looks like this:

```
class WebViewController : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView,
        url: String
    ): Boolean {
        view.loadUrl(url)
        view.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966760/how-i-get-page-source-from-webview