# Convert WebView Navigated method Forms to Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to convert WebView `Navigated` method from Xammarin.Forms to Xamarin.Android, What is equivalent to android.
See code below

```
</StackLayout>
    <WebView x:Name="Browser" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" Navigated="webOnEndNavigating" />
</StackLayout>
```

I tried below but doesn't seems to be working

```
public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
{
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page url=>" + url);
    if (url.Contains(Paynetz.model.PaynetzConfig.GetResponseExpression()))
    {
        result = paynetz.ValidateResponse();
        view.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: By `convert WebView Navigated method from Xammarin.Forms to Xamarin.Android`, what do you mean? Call Android method?

Comment: Yes exactly! I have above xaml code in Forms, I need to write that in Xam.android, `Navigated` event specially I need to convert

Comment: Why not use `Custom Renderers`?

Comment: FYI, In have separate Xam.android project for that I need to write code, Not for Forms project.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, `OnPageFinished` is a callback method.

Comment: Ok, But there should equivalent event (of `Navigated`) in android too for WebView.

Comment: I haven't used the `Navigated` event with WebView on Android. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334067/get-the-webview-navigation-event) will help you.