# How to access HTML source from Android WebView?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a simple browser app. It loads some IP and displays it using WebView. I want to access the source code of the loaded URL and store into Android string so I can use it.

**For an example :**

Suppose it is loaded 10.0.0.1 and the webpage shows this.

[image: LOADED HTML FILE]

So, I want to store that "HELLO THERE". And further want to process if string is equal to "HELLO THERE", a toast will be shown.

I managed to load the URL, and I know how to make Toast. The problem is, I am not able to store that "HELLO THERE" in string.

**Solution Tried :**

1. http://blog.weinigel.se/2014/03/05/getting-html-source-from-android-webview.html
2. [Is there a way to get the HTML in a webview in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543663/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-html-in-a-webview-in-an-android-app)
3. [How I get page source from WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966760/how-i-get-page-source-from-webview)

I have tried all of above solutions. But, none worked. It would be great if I get the answer using specific scenario of mine.

Comment: Can you tell if there was some exception thrown or error using those solutions or it just didn't do anything? Also your implementation could have been wrong

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268764/9796205

Comment: @javdromero there's no exception or error. Atleast not that catch (Exception e) block printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my quesntion's solution in this post.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503574/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-url-in-android[][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503574/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-url-in-android%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

I don't know much about Ion dependency but it did my work.